# How to get JBL Connect+ Stereo Mode working on Ubuntu?

Tags: bluetooth-speaker

JBL Flip 4 has the option to play in stereo with 2 speakers both connected. On my Android tablet this is possible via JBL Connect+ app. You can link both speakers through a separate button on the devices and switch to stereo mode in the app then assign which is left and right.

Is there an option to do this with Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm also interested in getting this to work. I assume the app is just a fancy remote that sends one or a few commands to switch the speakers from all mono mode to stereo mode and assign which one is left and right. This could have been implemented with some button combinations on the devices, but I have not found a hint for such a thing so far. Next step would be to record what's being sent to the speakers from the android app with a sniffer, but I couldn't get this to work right now. Sony (and other?) have the same functionality, probably not interoperable. We will see.

Comment: I wrote a mail to JBL support, they said they forwarded my message to their development team who will (eventually?) to a look at it how switching to stereo mode can be achieved with a button combination. Looking further I found some sites hacking these speakers and taking a very deep look into them and listing button combinations the JBL FAQ doesn't tell you about. I also got sniffing bluetooth traffic working on my phone, now I need to figure out what to do with the data. Some people wrote about "hacking" their watches an light bulbs, but I'm still confused about what to do.